# Como alterar o tamanho de uma :before ou :after dinamicamente com JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível alterar o tamanho de uma :before ou :after dinamicamente com jquery?

**Ex:**

```
$('#elemento:before').css({'width':'100px'});
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais completo em sua questão, eu não consegui entender

Comment: @JulioHenrique, vamos dizer que esse before seja de um elemento pai que está com seu width com 100%, mas o before precisa estar com o width de um elemento filho que é adicionado adinamicamente. Espero ter conseguido explicar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não consegue ter acesso a *pseudo-elementos* via JavaScript porque eles não fazem parte do DOM. O que você pode fazer é criar uma classe específica com novos estilos e adicionar ao elemento.

No exemplo abaixo, veja que o `::after` tem inicialmente 50% de `width`, e após adicionar a classe `.after`, ele passou a ter 10%:

```js
// adiciona a classe que altera o width do ::after
$("#teste").addClass("after");
```

```css
#teste{
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
}

#teste::after{
   content: 'after';
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
}

/* classe que irá alterar o ::after */
#teste.after::after{
   width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
   principal
</div>
```

### Edit

Você pode injetar um CSS dinâmico na página e fazer o mesmo como no exemplo acima, mas agora com o `width` de acordo com o do elemento-filho.

Abaixo o `::before` possui a mesma largura do elemento principal (`100%`). Após adicionar um elemento-filho, o script muda o `width` do `::before` adicionando a classe `.before`, que tem o mesmo `width` do elemento adicionado de forma dinâmica:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   
   $("#teste").append('<div id="filho">filho</div>');

   var filhoW = $("#filho").width();
   
   $("body").append("<style>#teste.before::before{width: "+filhoW+"px;}</style>");
   
   $("#teste").addClass("before");
   
});
```

```css
#teste{
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
}

#teste::before{
   content: 'before';
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   background: yellow;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}

#filho{
   width: 80px;
   background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
   abc
</div>
<button type="button">Adicionar filho</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado @dvd pelo esclarecimento, para o meu caso essa solução não é viável mas para algum companheiro aqui esse meio deve ajudar, mesmo assim agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Entendi. Mas editei a resposta com uma nova solução. Criar um estilo dinâmico usando a mesma técnica do primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Valeu, isso resolveu o problema