# Alterar content de ::after

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte **estrutura**:

```
<div class=duvidas>
   <div>
       <span>Titulo</span>
       <div style='display: none'>Texto</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

O **objetivo** é **clicar** em um `span` e **alterar** o `content` do `span` de '*+*' para '*-*'

E tornar o `display` da `div` de `none` para `block`.

```
$('div.duvidas > div').click(function(){
    if ($(this).find ('span').css('display') == 'none') {
      $(this).find ('span::after').attr('data-content','-');
      $(this).find ('div').css('display', 'block');    
    } else {
      $(this).find ('span::after').attr('data-content','+');
      $(this).find ('div').css('display', 'none');    
    }
  })
```

Mas não está funcionando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-elementos não são acessíveis via JavaScript ([veja a duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286587/como-alterar-o-tamanho-de-uma-before-ou-after-dinamicamente-com-jquery)). O que você pode fazer para alterá-los é adicionando uma classe que altera o `::after` no CSS. Agora há problemas no seu JavaScript, onde você deveria verificar no `if` se a div está visível, e não o span.

Note no CSS abaixo que quando a div possui a classe `.ativo`, o `content` do `::after` é alterado.

Veja:

```js
$('div.duvidas > div').click(function(){
   if (!$(this).find('div').is(':visible')){ // verifica se a div está visível
      $(this)
      .find('span') // busca o span
      .addClass('ativo') // adiciona a classe
      .end() // volta pro $(this)
      .find('div') // busca a div
      .show(); // mostra a div
   } else {
      $(this)
      .find('span')
      .removeClass('ativo')
      .end()
      .find('div')
      .hide();
   }
})
```

```css
span::after{
   content: '+';
}

span.ativo::after{
   content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=duvidas>
   <div>
       <span>Titulo</span>
       <div style='display: none'>Texto</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, Sam, obrigado deu certo. Mas olha só: Não tem apenas 1 div.duvidas.div, são várias. Como fazer para quando abrir uma, fechar também a div da outra que está aberta e ficar apenas 1?

Comment: Adiciona isso antes do if: `$('div.duvidas > div').not(this).find("span").removeClass("ativo").end().find('div').hide();`

Comment: Funcionou! Muito grato. Agora vou dar uma olhada com mais atenção

Comment: como ficaria se eu quisesse colocar um efeito transition: height 0.8s; na hora que for abrir e fechar?

Comment: Teria que fazer no JS porque o CSS não vai saber a altura do elemento para aplicar o height exato.

Comment: ficaria   .addClass('ativo').css(''transitions,'height 0.8s')?

Comment: Não, teria que usar .slideToggle

Comment: Vou ter que sair agora, quando eu voltar te mostro um exemplo.

Comment: de boa. consegui aqui: .slideToggle( "slow" ) obrigado!